Errors resulting from running memoize locally: (\pdfpageattr undefined), (No file MWE.memo.dir/...)
I am trying to move to locally running my documents. In doing this, I have actually been quite successful - all of my packages except one are running smoothly.
Pardon me if this is a silly question, but I can't seem to get memoize to work right now - which is strange, since it worked before. I just want some help troubleshooting the error.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{memoize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw[red] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);

Hello World!

\tikz \draw[green] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\end{document}

The log is huge, so I will post a snippet of it.
c:/Users/twill/TeX_Folder/MWE.tex:5: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pdfpageattr 
             {/Rotate 0}
l.5 \tikz \draw[red] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
                                           
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

[1]
No file MWE.memo.dir/89CF3ABB71B828505525EA2E771A5C63-E778DCCCB8AAB0BBD3F6CFEEFD2421F8.pdf
c:/Users/twill/TeX_Folder/MWE.tex:5: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pdfpageattr 
             {/Rotate 0}
l.5 \tikz \draw[red] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
                                           
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.


\pdfpageattr is a pdflatex command so presumably you are using a different engine such as lualatex, but the packages should have detected that and use suitable back end commands

@DavidCarlisle I am using lualatex. Do you have any advice as to how I can overcome this?

no I just tried on lualatex and I get the same, you could try adding \usepackage{luatex85}  before memoize to give the pdflatex names in lualatex but that should never be needed. there are others here with more knowledge of memoize though who will probably answer

@DavidCarlisle Thank you for your time. I will give loading that package a try, as well as wait for a a response from someone who is more familiar with memoize.

note I corrected the luatex85 package name (you might have expected I would know the names of packages I co-authored, but apparently not)

@DavidCarlisle Haha, thank you :-) I can report that this solution works.

you could load the pdfmanagement with \DocumentMetadata{}. memoize then doesn't try to add a rotation attribute. But you should report that anyway, the attribute doesn't make much sense.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you for your input. How would one go about reporting this? If you want, you could do the honors - as I suspect you could articulate the problem better than I.

can somebody post a complete log? I do not get this error with luatex. but I've not got the most recent update of either memoize or latex. I suspect this is related to an attempt to fix a bug in the version now on ctan. when I tested an earlier version of the fix, it broke in xetex, but not luatex ....

@Jasper I just came back to delete my comment. I can reproduce without updating my system ;). now I have my own log ;).

@Jasper by the way, if you compile interactively, you can cut the log significantly. mine is within the site limit, for example:  547  1604 21714 jasper-test.log so I still have over 8000 characters to play with ;).

@cfr do you mean with interaction=nonstopmode?

@Jasper no, I mean NOT that ;). my guess is your log has the same error over and over. in any case, can you try adding \makeatletter\def\mmz@shipout@unrotate{}\makeatother to your preamble and see if that works?

@Jasper you have to add it after loading memoize.

@cfr I added \makeatletter\def\mmz@shipout@unrotate{}\makeatother and removed interaction=nonstopmode. It is now taking a long time to compile, compared to before. In fact,itis still compiling, it maybe in a loop.

what command are you compiling with? I ran your example code with lualatex and it finished very quickly.

are you compiling the example you posted or something else? can you try in a clean directory?

@cfr you are right, it was in my working directory. It runs in a clean one

@cfr the problem was that you cant use \makeatother in a .sty (in my document) that's why it worked in a clean directory when I used it in the preamble.

Update: should be fixed in v1.4.1 if I'm not mistaken.

Reported at https://github.com/sasozivanovic/memoize/issues/34#issue-2708360076.
Workaround:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{memoize}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\sys_if_engine_luatex:T
{
  \def\mmz@shipout@unrotate{}%
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tikz \draw[red] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);

Hello World!

\tikz \draw[green] (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
\end{document}

Note that this may cause problems if you use pdflscape and create externs in landscape orientation when compiling with LuaTeX. I haven't checked this, but, if LuaTeX is used, the code undoes a commit intended to fix an issue with pdflscape. However, since that fix actually breaks memoize whether landscape is used or not when LuaTeX is used, undoing provides at least a quick fix if you're not rotating memoized content.

but I'm not sure the fix is even required with luatex?

Is it safe now to remove the fix from my document, or will it take some time for this update to be released \usepackage-wise? When will it be safe to remove the fix?

@Jasper do you use TeX Live or MikTeX? Either way, don't remove it yet, no. The fix is on CTAN, but it takes at least a day or two for TeX Live to pick it up and the mirrors to sync. TeX Live picking it up requires somebody to manually re-package it from CTAN. But they are usually very quick. MikTeX usually take longer.

I use TeX Live (MiKTeX has some issues). Good to know - I will tlmgr update self and remove the fix in a week to be safe. Thank you.

Forgot to give you the tick! Sorry about that.

@Jasper It should be Sašo's tick really.

If Sašo decides to answer, I will happily switch the tick. You did play a big role in reaching a solution though.

@Jasper well, I know he read my first comment ;).

@Jasper I just got the update from the Warwick server, so TL seem to have picked it up.

thank you for letting me know
